# C++ std::find_if on a custom class

Tags: c++, vector, find

I have a std::vector of a custom class (Term).   I'm trying to find terms in that class using the std::find_if construct.   I'm missing something:

**Term.h**

```
 

    #ifndef _TERM_H_
    #define _TERM_H_

    #include <string>

    class Term {
        public:
                Term() {}
                Term(std::string, float);

                void setTerm(std::string myTerm) {this->term   = myTerm;}
                void setWeight(float myWeight) {this->weight = myWeight;}

                std::string getTerm() const {return this->term;}
                float getWeight() {return this->weight;}

                bool operator<(Term &t) {return t.getWeight() <  this->getWeight();}
                bool operator==(const Term *t) const {return this->getTerm().compare(t->getTerm()) == 0;}

        private:
                std::string term;
                float weight;
    }; // end class

    #endif
```

Then, later in the code, I have another class (Document) where I'll be comparing vectors of those terms:
**Document.cpp**

```
    /***
     Defined in the header file:
     std::vector<Term *> terms;

     For brevity, I've removed other function definitions....***/

    void Document::compareToDoc(Document *myDoc) {
        for(auto const& term : myDoc->getTerms()) {
                //auto it = find(terms.begin(), terms.end(), term);
                auto it = find_if(terms.begin(), terms.end(),
                                  [](const Term *t1){return t1->getTerm() = term->getTerm();});

                if(it != terms.end()) {
                        std::cout << " .. found" << std::endl;
                } // end if
        } // end for
    } // compareToDoc
```

I'm pretty confused on what the lambda expression should look like to find terms that are the same.  I tried the std::find route (commented out), but it never finds when two terms match.  I believe find_if is the correct function, but I'm now struggling with the lambda.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: The right direction would be your C++ book, which explains the difference between `=` and `==`. You're not comparing anything in your lambda.

Comment: What does `myDoc->getTerms()` return, and what is the resulting type for `term`?

Comment: @Sam, yep.  Changed that and still get the same error at compile time about "term is not captured"

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm:  myDoc->getTerms returns a reference to a vector of Term *.   The definition in the header file looks like:

 std::vector<Term *> &getTerms()    {return this->terms;}

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.   The std::find_if line must look like this:

```
auto it = find_if(terms.begin(), terms.end(),
                              [&term](const Term *t1){return t1->getTerm() == term->getTerm();});
```